# All four data nodes in MySQL Cluster in same node group

Tags: replication, mysql-cluster

I am testing MySQL Cluster 7.2. I have two servers, `mysql1` and `mysql2`. I want the management server and two data nodes to run on `mysql1` and two other data nodes to run on `mysql2`. My `config.ini` file looks like this:

```
[ndb_mgmd]
hostname=mysql1
datadir=/var/mysql-cluster/ndb_data
NodeId=1

[ndbd default]
noofreplicas=2
datadir=/var/mysql-cluster/ndb_data
DataMemory=8M

[ndbd]
hostname=mysql1
NodeId=3

[ndbd]
hostname=mysql2
NodeId=4

[ndbd]
hostname=mysql1
NodeId=13

[ndbd]
hostname=mysql2
NodeId=14

[mysqld]
NodeId=50
```

With this configuration I would expect, as per the MySQL Cluster documentation, that the two data nodes 3 and 4 would be in nodegroup 0, while the two data nodes 13 and 14 would be in nodegroup 1.

However, when I start everything up and show the nodes, I see this:

```
Connected to Management Server at: localhost:1186
Cluster Configuration
---------------------
[ndbd(NDB)]     4 node(s)
id=3    @192.168.0.42  (mysql-5.5.30 ndb-7.2.12, starting, Nodegroup: 0, Master)
id=4    @192.168.0.43  (mysql-5.5.30 ndb-7.2.12, starting, Nodegroup: 0)
id=13   @192.168.0.42  (mysql-5.5.30 ndb-7.2.12, starting, Nodegroup: 0)
id=14   @192.168.0.43  (mysql-5.5.30 ndb-7.2.12, starting, Nodegroup: 0)

[ndb_mgmd(MGM)] 1 node(s)
id=1    @192.168.0.42  (mysql-5.5.30 ndb-7.2.12)

[mysqld(API)]   1 node(s)
id=50 (not connected, accepting connect from any host)
```

Everything seems to be in nodegroup 0! What do I have to do to get 3 and 4 in one group and 13 and 14 in another?

Comment: I'm having the same question. I asked it here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094959/same-node-group-when-there-are-2-datanodes-and-rf-is-1-in-mysql-cluster
And I started a bounty on your question as it seems a common problem.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug [1] in MySQL. It happens because your data nodes are still starting. Node-group IDs should be shown correctly once they are started completely.

[1] http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=30831

Comment: That bug is 7 years old, I'd be surprised if it wasn't already fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Put "NodeGroup" value in each data node and it will solve it .

For more information read : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-cluster-nodes-groups.html

Answer (score 0):

Start them one by one, this way it will connect two data nodes to each SQL Node.(bearing in mind you will have to clear cache file which gets generated in `mysql-cluster/` folder) and `ps aux | grep ndb` or `ps aux | grep sql` exit them all before trying it out.
Your config file looks to be pointing only to 1x SQL node.
Change it to:

```
[ndb_mgmd]
hostname=mgm.yourname
datadir=/var/mysql-cluster/ndb_data
NodeId=1

[ndbd default]
noofreplicas=4
datadir=/var/mysql-cluster/ndb_data
DataMemory=8M

[ndbd]
hostname=ndb1.forsql1
NodeId=3

[ndbd]
hostname=ndb2.forsql1
NodeId=4

[ndbd]
hostname=ndb3.forsql2
NodeId=13

[ndbd]
hostname=ndb4.forsql2
NodeId=14

[mysqld]
NodeId=50

[mysqld]
NodeId=51
```

Enter `ndbd` on ndb1.forsql1 Data node,

Enter `ndbd` on ndb2.forsql1 Data node,

Enter `sqld` on 1st SQL node,

Enter `ndbd` on ndb3.forsql2 Data node,

Enter `ndbd` on ndb4.forsql2 Data node,

Enter `sqld` on 2nd SQL node.

Wait and be patient till it connects and shows automatically on ndb_mgm > console that node x: has been started only then proceed. Another way to check is to find by typing `all report memory` and check if it has replicated the data only then proceed if it has.